# Is it possible to prevent the header("location: url") from being sent to AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've a html form on a page. The form data is sent via AJAX to a PHP script. Within this PHP script, each of the `$_POST`'s from the inputs are checked conditionally using a variety of if statements. If the condition doesn't meet a specific `strlen` / other criteria then I echo a message into the AJAX returndata and `exit()` the PHP script.

Assuming all conditions are met, at the bottom of my PHP script I have applied a url that is built from variables within the PHP script itself and concatenated inside, like so:

`header("location: view_topic.php?tid='".$tid."'&page='".$page."'");`

**The issue:**

Since I am generating the url within the PHP script, and am only able to generate it in there, I am having to either use PHP `header("location: ...")` as a redirect, or having to echo the url, which in turn sends it to the returndata, then use `window.location(returndata)` in my JavaScript/AJAX.

I've done some homework and have noticed a known issue with the header method, when set is being sent to the AJAX returndata. This means that the entire header location page is being displayed in a tiny invisible div where I display my errors for the above mentioned conditional error messages generated in the PHP script.

**The question:**

In the below code is my alternative method of setting the `window.location(returndata)`.

Here I am echoing the actual url generated by my PHP variables, which sends it to the returndata. However when submitting the form I am returned to the same page, and the returndata is simply echo'd out from the PHP at the top.

Does anyone know how to prevent the `header("location: ...");` from being sent to the AJAX returndata, or have any other solutions on the method below?

Thanks in advance,
Richie.

**My AJAX:**

```
$("#topic_form").submit(function(event){
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
    url: 'create_topic_parse.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
        success: function (returndata) {
            if(returndata.indexOf("view_topic") != true){
                $('#message').css("color", "red").html(returndata);
                } else {
                window.location(returndata);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Why use ajax if you are just going to change the page anyway?

Comment: A header should not appear in the body content. A location header in an AJAX response will cause the browser to transparently follow the redirect though, and return the content of the redirected page instead (except old Opera, which did not). You could return your URL in a custom header, like `X-Redirect` or something.

Comment: Because I'm having to generate the url in PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of returning html, return json:

```
{"action": "display","html":"..."}
```

or

```
{"action":"redirect","location":"url"}
```

and change:

```
    success: function (response) {
        if(response.action == "display"){
            $('#message').css("color", "red").html(response.html);
        } else if (response.action == "redirect") {
            window.location(response.location);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see. I'll give this a whirl and let you know how I get on. Cheers man.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, If I understand correctly. You want to use `create_topic_parse.php`, to generate a URL which you would then like to be redirected to.

Currently the page you want redirecting to, is displaying in a div on your existing page and not redirecting.

I think that in your PHP file, if you echo a meta refresh instead of a `header()` then this should get you the results you want.

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=view_topic.php?tid=".$tid."&page=".$page."\">";
```

These have always worked as part of the body for me.